# Is this an Error in Griffiths Electrodynamics?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential, voltage, boundary-conditions

Check Problem 3.43 in *Griffiths Introduction to Electrodynamics*

> A conducting sphere of radius $a$, at potential $V_0$, is surrounded by a thin concentric spherical shell of radius $b$, over which someone has glued a surface charge $\sigma(\theta)=k\cos(\theta)$ where $k$ is a constant and $\theta$ is the polar angle.

It then asks to find the potential in the $r>b$ and $a<r<b$. The answer provided by the book is:
$V(r, θ) =  \frac{aV_0}{r} + \frac{(b^3 − a^3)k \cos θ}{3r^2 \epsilon_0}, r ≥ b,$

$V(r, θ) =  \frac{aV_0}{r} + \frac{(r^3 − a^3)k \cos θ}{3r^2 \epsilon_0}, r ≤ b$

Credit: *Griffiths, David J.. Introduction to Electrodynamics (p. 162). Cambridge University Press. Kindle Edition*.

Solving for the region in between the discs: using the boundary condition $V(a,\theta)=V_0$ we find that:
$$V(a,\theta)=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}{(A_la^{l}+\frac{B_l}{a^{l+1}})P_l(\cos\theta)}=V_0$$
Since $V_0$ is a constant, and thus has no $\theta$ dependence, we conclude the only term in the series must be the one with $l=0$ to ensure that the left side of the equation has no terms in $\cos \theta$. Thus in summary we find that:
$$A_0+\frac{B_0}{a}=V_0$$
and thus the potential has the form:
$$V(r,\theta)=A_0+\frac{a(V_0-A_0)}{r}$$
but this will obviously not satisfy the form given by the answer in the book, as it must have a $\cos \theta$ term and of course the $A_l$'s and $B_l$'s are constants. I am probably at fault, but I don't see where exactly. Please help.

Comment: Whenever in doubt, you can check the errata for the book. You can find all the corrected errors directly on the [website of Griffiths himself](https://www.reed.edu/physics/faculty/griffiths/)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since $V_0$ is a constant, and thus has no $\theta$ dependence, we conclude the only term in the series must be the one with $l=0$ ...

This implies that

$$A_la^l+\frac{B_l}{a^{l+1}}=0$$

for $l>0$. It doesn’t imply that $A_l=B_l=0$.